# $("<element>") Equivalent in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So we can create elements by $("<element>") with jQuery and work with it without showing it on screen.

Is there any way like in React Native? Create element, dont show it on screen and get results to use for other purpose.

Comment: Can you tell scenario behind it so that I'll be able to help you?

Comment: Why don't you create the element outside of the viewport? Maybe something like `<View style={{position: 'absolute', top: -20000}} />`